# DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

```
Android Studio 0.8.10
```

Hello

I am trying to implement a Navigation drawer, but I keep getting this error. The fragment extends the ListFragment and I have overriden the getview to inflate the layout below. I have an activity that add the fragment and initializes the DrawLayar class.
I am using the Navigation drawer and have the following layout `fragment_listfott.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dlMenus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navi_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffc6c6c6"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_large"
        android:contentDescription="Picture displaying logo"/>
</LinearLayout>  
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In my `FottListFragment.java` I have the following:

```
private class NewsFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsFeed> {

        public NewsFeedAdapter(ArrayList<NewsFeed> newsFeedArrayList) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, newsFeedArrayList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_listfott, null);
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

And in the `MainActivity.java` where I do all the Drawlayer stuff

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_listfott);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navi_fragment_container);

        if (fragment == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.navi_fragment_container, new FottListFragment(), "FottListFragment")
                    .commit();
        }

        /* Navigation drawer */
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dlMenus);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.menu_btn,
                R.string.open_draw,
                R.string.close_draw) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, as this has been a problem for a few days now.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You should not be using the DrawerLayout for your ListView rows. That is, it shouldn't be the layout you're inflating in `getView()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Are you staying that getView cannot be used with DrawLayer. Our customer would like to have a Navigation draw that can be open when the ListView items are displayed.

Comment: The Adapter's `getView()` method, in this case, returns the Views for the rows of a ListView. I don't think you want a drawer in every row in your ListView. With a simple ArrayAdapter, it's usually a simple layout, like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. You're already creating the main Navigation Drawer with `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_listfott)`.

Comment: I think I understand. I would have the layout just for the listView items that will be inflated in the getView. However, I would need another layout that will contain the navigation draw?

Comment: `R.layout.fragment_listfott` is the main Navigation Drawer layout. You need a layout for the rows in the ListView that uses `NewsFeedAdapter`.

Comment: @MikeM Thanks, the penny finally dropped. If you answer this question I will mark you as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout that's inflated in the `getView()` method is, in this case, the layout for the individual rows of the ListView that uses `NewsFeedAdapter`. Since `R.layout.fragment_listfott` contains the DrawerLayout that's meant for the app's Navigation Drawer, it shouldn't be the layout inflated and returned there. Rather, that layout should be the one that defines the rows, and for a simple ArrayAdapter, is often like the SDK's `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, which is just a TextView.